# Unity drop object to panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Dynamically made GameObject cant drop to a Panel made in Unity UI.
I try all the method of Idrag,Idrop thing, cant work in my case.
So what i wanna achieve is this

1. Random Gameobject able to drop on the list
2. Item on the List can be ordered through Vertical Layout Group

[Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1oQl.png) of the Panel UI

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you want to arrange a 'later' dynamically created object in the UI ?

Comment: This question is far from coherent, thus the downvote.

Comment: @DieterMeemken Yes, thats the idea.

Comment: @Krythic The problem is, i cant find anyone with similar problems, i also dont know how to make a good title related to my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically parent a GameObject you have instantiated you do it through the object's transform. It has a parent field.

[Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

Comment: This is need even for a Panel object?

Comment: A panel is really just a GameObject like any other with a CanvasRenderer and an Image component. Beyond the rect transform it's a GameObject like any other. So yes.